# Linear Algebra, Geometric Representation of the Span of a Set of Vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, geometric-interpretation

Given the vectors: [4, 3, 3], [0, 1, 1], and [-1, 0, 0]

The question: Is the vector [4, 4, 3] in the span of the set?
I believe it is NOT, since putting the augmented matrix for this set in row-reduced echelon form results in an inconsistent set.

Now, I am asked to give a geometric interpretation of the set. I thought it would be a plane (since it can't be a 3D space if the vector is not in the span), but I am unsure about what the answer is and how to reach it. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! *Hint*: determine the rank of the matrix with row reduction.

Answer (score 1):

It is  not because in any linear combinations of the given vectors the second and third coordinates are always the same.  The span is the plane $\{(x,y,z): y=z\}$.